# Detect editText text changed when user erases editText

Tags: java, android

I have an `editText` that serves as search bar, every time the text in the `editText` changes, we fetch results in real time from firebase database. Everything looks good. The problem is my current configuration to detect text edits doesn't seem to detect when user completely erases the text from the editText. The condition works if the user clicks backspace a char at a time, however if the user holds the backspace (in order to delete everything completely) the condition results false.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    String searchText = searcheditext.getText().toString();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (searchText != null && !searchText.isEmpty()) {
        // Text is not null or empty, add the fragment
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Search_tag_fragment(searchText), "cerca");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    } else {
        // Text is null or empty, remove the Search_tag_fragment if it exists
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("cerca");

        if (fragment instanceof Search_tag_fragment) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searcheditext.getWindowToken(), 0);
        
        // Clear focus from the EditText
        searcheditext.clearFocus();
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

As you can see I'm using `afterTextChanged()`